# Запуск задачи субпроекта в gradle

Tags: java, gradle

В главном проекте есть подпроект `'uploader'`. (точнее просто просто папка с ещё одним `gradle` проектом)
Мне надо, чтобы при выполнении таска в главном проекте, выполнялся таск в подпроекте. А именно таск `run` с определёнными параметрами. (такие как путь до собранной в главном проекте `jar` итп)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В build.gradle корневого проекта надо добавить задачу, которая будет вызывать gradle в подпроекте с нужными параметрами:

```
task runUploader(type: GradleBuild) {
  buildFile = 'uploader/build.gradle'  
  tasks = ['run']  
  startParameter.projectProperties = [jarDir: "/jardir"]
}
```

и добавить зависимости, чтобы эта задача вызывалась в нужный момент, например так:

```
myTask.dependsOn runUploader
```